# CPT Loop, include taxonomies and disclude others?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have a query for a CPT that works to not include certain taxonomies:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'postype', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby'=>'menu_order','order'=>'ASC', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'department',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('tax-to-ignore-1', 'tax-to-ignore-2'),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        )
    ),) );
```

Now, I also have another query for the same post type that works, where I only include a certain taxonomy:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post_type', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby'=>'menu_order','order'=>'ASC', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'department',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'tax-to-include',
        )
    ),) );
```

Both of these are working independently, but how would I include one taxonomy, while also making sure to ignore other taxonomies? The rule would be for if a post is in both the include and ignore taxonomy, to ignore them.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: That's simply not possible to do in a single WP Query. In that case I suggest to put the ignore tax's also in an array in your code and while you loop through the included query check if it has a tax corresponding with the ignore array and then simply ignore it in your output

Comment: Thanks, is there an easy way to see if the taxonomy includes certain names inside the loop?

Comment: Hi - your examples use the same taxonomy so I'm a bit confused.  Can you give a clearer example of what you want to achieve?  You certainly *can* make much more complex taxonomy queries, but I need to understand the question better before trying some code for you.

Comment: Ah - I think you mean _term_ to include and _terms_ to ignore. _Department_ is your taxonomy, but things like _accounts_, _sales_, _marketing_ would be terms within it. So, are you looking to make a query that includes all posts with a particular term except for any posts with a separate list of terms?